# i get this error code Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/koloyxlj/public_html/login.php on line 19

Tags: php

this is my code i learned this via a tutorial so this is not my own code but what did i do wrong?

i look forward to hearing from you guys

opening php tag

```
$username = "";
$password = "";
$hostname = "";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Really could not connect to database!");

$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

$myusername = $_POST['user'];
$mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close();

if($count==1) {
    echo 'It worked!';
}
```

closing php tag

Comment: echo mysql_error($dbhandle); try this

Comment: No username and no hostname !!!!!!

Comment: i deleted the username and host name for this question

Comment: Your query has failed to return any rows

Comment: why do have deleted so? add in them then run code and use **or die(mysql_error());**

Comment: so why would my query fail to return any rows?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790790/php-warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole

Comment: please make your database configuration. And replace $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle); with $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) :-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 
Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
die(mysql_error($dbhandle));
```